# colsum from a chisq test

Tags: r

The results from a chisq test appears as below , i need the sum of statistic (chisq) only, colsum is not working. How will i only get the statistic sum?

```
    statistic parameter p.value      
1   120       9         1.336165e-21
2   115.2397  21        5.292644e-15
3   114.9731  18        3.703771e-16
4   85.85785  21        8.283122e-10
5   103.7818  30        4.650999e-10
6   85.44727  24        8.062478e-09
7   42.03636  18        0.001093033 
8   42.31688  24        0.01188941  
9   72.22857  24        1.000100e-06
10  54.47273  24        0.0003685193
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something along the lines of:

```
sum(object_name[ , 1])  # should work for matrix or dataframe
```

If it's a data.frame you could have written:

```
 sum(object_name$statistic)
```

Sometimes an object has a matrix buried "one layer below" or even "two layers below" where it *should* be. Perhaps this dput result could be used   ... not saying it is like yours but it does have a list class and it would print something like yours:

```
    object_name <-list(list(structure(c(1, 120, 9, 1.336165e-21, 2, 115.2397, 21, 
5.292644e-15, 3, 114.9731, 18, 3.703771e-16, 4, 85.85785, 21, 
8.283122e-10, 5, 103.7818, 30, 4.650999e-10, 6, 85.44727, 24, 
8.062478e-09, 7, 42.03636, 18, 0.001093033, 8, 42.31688, 24, 
0.01188941, 9, 72.22857, 24, 1.0001e-06, 10, 54.47273, 24, 0.0003685193
), .Dim = c(10L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("rown", "statistic", 
"parameter", "p.value")))))

> str(object_name)
List of 1
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:10, 1:4] 1.00 1.20e+02 9.00 1.34e-21 2.00 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "rown" "statistic" "parameter" "p.value"
```

You need to use [[1]] twice to get "deep enough" to access the "statistic" column:

```
object_name[[1]][[1]][ , "statistic"] 
sum( object_name[[ 1 ]][[1]][, "statistic"] )
#[1] 267.6397
```

Comment: It`s a list, even after changing as dataframe or matrix, it`s still not working.

Comment: @Ram - You may have to provide more information than simply 'it's not working'. Edit your question to include the output of `dput(your_object)`.

Comment: @Ram : post dput(object.name)

Comment: The results are stored in a vector, which is a list. when i try to get the 1st column (statistic) from the list, i get a list back and when i try to sum , it gives an error msg, invalid 'type' (list) of argument. I also tried it as dataframe and as matrix, still same error.

Comment: @Ram - Once again, post `dput(your_object)`.

Comment: Ram: your description is still too vague.  Please `dput` (or possibly post the results of `str`), as we are requesting ... If the results were a list, then @DWin's second suggestion should have worked, unless it's stored internally as an *unnamed* list, in which case you might try `sum(object_name[[1]])`

Comment: Really sorry for poor description of question. Dwins suggestion works. Thank you all for ur support.